# Show that the interior of the set A is empty?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider $A = \{(x, \sin\frac{1}{x}) \mid 0< x \leq 1 \}$, a subset of $\mathbb R^2$. Find int($A$).

We can see graphically that the interior of $A$ is definitely empty, but I want to check by the definition of interior point. Let if possible there exist a point $(a,b) \in \operatorname{int}(A)$. Then there exists an open ball $(p,q) \times (r,s)$ such that $(a,b) \in (p,q)\times (r,s) \subseteq A$ .

**Please give me a hint, How to get a contradiction ?**

Comment: Any point in the interior is a point of $A$, so it has the form $(x,\sin(1/x))$.

Comment: Andres :I know int$(A) \subseteq A$, but how to conclude that no open set contained in $A$.

Comment: How many points are in the intersection of an open ball and a vertical line?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $r < y < s$. The basic open set $(p,q) \times (r,s)$ contains the line $(p,q) \times \{y\}$. Is it possible that this line is contained in that subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Answer (score 0):

Let a point $$P=( a, sin(1/a))\in A$$

For any $\epsilon >0$, the open ball $B(P;\epsilon)$ includes  the point $$Q=( a, sin(1/a)+\epsilon /2 )$$ but $Q$ is not in $A.$

Thus no open ball around $P$ is contained in $A.$

That is , the interior of $A$ is empty.